# Powerline and gdb

Tags: bash, prompt, gdb, powerline

**GDB in TUI-Mode** shows strange behaviour. I'm using powerline and it seems that the font is the wrong one. Exist there a solution to have a pretty command line?

How can I invoke a program not using the powerline environment?

[image: gdb invoked by a bash-shell using powerline]

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The reason was a .gdbinit file, which colorize my gdb. However invoking gdb the following way solved the problem, but the colorize does not work now.

```
> gdb -n -tui filename
```